# WCF Invoking From .Net 2.0 Applications

Tags: .net, wcf, asmx

if there are more than one bindings ( ie in Web.config) in WCF Services, how to differentiate and consume Basic HTTP bindings from .net 2.0 Framework.

Comment: Duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2069288/can-an-asp-net-2-0-web-site-reference-wcf-web-services

Answer (score 0):

Using Add Web Reference will only work with HTTP bindings.

Comment: how should be the code to implement HTTP Bindings from .net 2.0 Applications. For Example In 3.0, for the service class we have Bindings specified constructor. [Service = new Service("wsHTTPBinding")].

Comment: You can't create WCF bindings in .NET 2.0, you would need to generate a proxy using Add Web Reference.